# Logging a web service

Tags: .net, web-services, logging, web-config

I want to create a log for my .net webservice
I know that using HTTPModule in web.config can achieve that but not sure how to use it.

i googled and searched here but no example of how to do that.

I wonder if there is another way or a proper example of how to use HTTPModule to log all service calls

Comment: you can use log4net for all your logging needs

Comment: what is log4net?

Comment: This is what you need. Google for it